# Tomcat con IIS proxy reverso

Tags: genexus

Tengo una webapp Java 11 desplegada en un Tomcat 9 que utiliza WebSockets. Probando la aplicacion contra el Tomcat directamente funciona perfecto. En cambio, si colocamos el Tomcat detras de un IIS haciendo de proxy reverso dejan de funcionar los WebSockets.

El web.config del sitio es algo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="cl_websocket" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(gxwebsocket.+)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="ws://localhost:8080/CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

He notado que los requests desde el IIS al Tomcat llegan y parecerian ser los correctos, pero lo raro es que se repiten cada 10 segundos, es como que me falta algo pero no logro darme cuenta.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Aug/2021:08:06:28 -0300] "GET /CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/gxwebsocket?a83a4da4-6338-4ede-88a8-1e80650193af HTTP/1.1" 101 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Aug/2021:08:06:39 -0300] "GET /CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/gxwebsocket?a83a4da4-6338-4ede-88a8-1e80650193af HTTP/1.1" 101 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Aug/2021:08:06:49 -0300] "GET /CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/gxwebsocket?a83a4da4-6338-4ede-88a8-1e80650193af HTTP/1.1" 101 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Aug/2021:08:06:59 -0300] "GET /CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/gxwebsocket?a83a4da4-6338-4ede-88a8-1e80650193af HTTP/1.1" 101 -

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [27/Aug/2021:08:07:09 -0300] "GET /CafeLindoJavaEnvironment/gxwebsocket?a83a4da4-6338-4ede-88a8-1e80650193af HTTP/1.1" 101 -
```

Answer (score 0):

me respondo a mi mismo. Por un lado no es necesario agregar una regla especifica para el gxwebsocket. Por otro lado, hay que agregar en las opciones de Java del Tomcat la siguiente linea:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true
```

De esta manera funciona perfectamente.